# Are my images not centered?

Tags: support, images

I wanted to layout my images in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/323591/199241) centered, and I believe they are. Though I am using an ISP that seems to have banned imgur so I used a proxy to check them out, and a comment suggested that they aren't. Are they? Are they centered on the desktop and/or mobile?

Comment: they look centered to me but that's a moot point since you've just stuck a bunch of `&nbsp;` infront as such those with larger displays it may be more to left and those with smaller screen it may be more to the right (depending on how small SE allows a screen to be before adding a scroll bar)

Comment: They are not at all for me on mobile. Also, why do you need them to be centered? Why not leave them justified as they are?

Comment: @Ash aesthetics. Why does one ever center anything?

Comment: @nae considering how much work it is, is it really worth it, though? Especially because what you have done is not consistent at all. It doesn't make it more readable and honestly, I wouldn't be surprised if someone edited them out to make it more consistently readable.

Comment: I had to give up centering.

Comment: @Ash Thanks for being bellicose about the point you're making. The images in the post now have a more consistent layout on all three platforms I can see.